# Grabbing videos from YouTube in PHP

Tags: php, html, youtube

I am trying to set up a script for grabbing youtube videos to download them in php here is my current script.

```
<html>
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {

$location = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
try {
    $handle = fopen($location, "r");
if($handle) {
    $contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}

fclose($handle);
$result1 = preg_match("/&t=([\w]*)&/",$contents,$tickets);
$result2 = preg_match("/v=(\w*)/",$location,$video_id);

if($result1) {
    echo "<a href = \"http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=";
    echo $video_id[1];
    echo "&t=";
    echo $tickets[1];
    echo "\">Download link.</a>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Click and Save";
}
    else echo "Damn! Click Back and try again..Sorry :(";
}
    else echo "\nYou liked that? Ha?";
}
    catch(Exception $e) {echo "I made an error. So what? COME AT ME BRO!";} 
}

else echo "Empty input! YOU'RE SO STUPID!";
?>
<br><br>
<a href="face.html">Back</a>
</hmtl>
```

I also have a simple HTML file that provides a place to paste a YouTube URL into a field and it runs the script above. However I am getting the echo

`Damn! Click Back and try again..Sorry :("`

I don't know why I am getting this error, the code looks solid to me any suggestions?

Comment: `var_dump($contents)`?

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader

Comment: [The way to get temporary Youtube video link with PHP & Curl - updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078023/issue-when-i-want-to-get-a-direct-url-from-youtube-via-php/55079527#55079527)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this a while back:

```
<?php
$id = 'O99Sqpxd0hE';
$format = 'video/mp4';
parse_str(file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . $id), $info);

$streams = $info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];

$streams = explode(',', $streams);

foreach($streams as $stream) {
    parse_str($stream, $data);
    if(stripos($data['type'], $format) !== false) {
        $video = fopen($data['url'] . '&signature=' . $data['sig'], 'r');
        $file = fopen($_GET['id'] . '.mp4', 'w');
        stream_copy_to_stream($video, $file);
        fclose($video);
        fclose($file);
        echo '<a href="./'.$_GET['id'].'.mp4">Download</a>';
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I like it, but the URL is the input to download the video from YouTube, so I can't have the ID identified already.

Comment: this code return error :
Notice: Undefined index: type line 12

Comment: @AnassElFakir This code is 5 years old so it's very possible that YouTube changed something. Feel free to post an updated version of my code when you figure out how to use it.